# a lot of heavy .txt files in my android. is it safe to delete them to free up memory?

Tags: internal-storage, delete, documents

There are lots of text documents in my android phone with over 1 mb size. they are typically named with time stamp like "20200419_11". is it safe to delete them? will it enhance my storage space

Comment: Depends on the content, though usually they are just log files to help debugging the app/system, and safe to delete as users.